# Active directory users based on numeric values not able to login

Tags: active-directory, sssd

Active directory based on numeric(01012578) not able to login
but wit the same DC we are able to login using name username Eg. syed
client o.s 20.0.4 desktop version
AD script

```
#!/bin/sh

#Linux 
 Ingration with Active Directory Script
#Author: Syed

#Install all required Components
echo Installation all Required Components

sudo apt install -y krb5-config
sudo apt install -y msktutil
sudo apt install -y samba
sudo apt-get install -y realmd sssd sssd-tools libpam-sss libnss-sss
sudo apt-get install -y krb5-user adcli packagekit
sudo apt-get install ntpdate

read -p "Enter your Domain name : " DomainName
echo using $DomainName

sudo ntpdate -q $DomainName
sudo ntpdate $DomainName

REALMD="/etc/realmd.conf"

/bin/cat <<EOM >$REALMD

automatic-install = no

EOM

sed -i '28isession optional      pam_mkhomedir.so  skel = /etc/skel/  mask=0077' /etc/pam.d/common-session

sudo realm discover $DomainName

sudo realm join $DomainName -U administrator --verbose

sudo realm list

sudo realm permit--all

sudo realm permit -g AD_group

sudo mv /etc/krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf.default

read -p "Enter your Domain System name : " SystemName

KRB5FILE="/etc/krb5.conf"

/bin/cat <<EOM >$KRB5FILE
[libdefaults]
default_realm = $DomainName
rdns = no
dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_lookup_realm = true

[realms]
$DomainName = {
kdc = $SystemName.$DomainName
admin_server = $SystemName.$DomainName
}

EOM

kinit syed

klist


read -p "Enter your Local Host name : " HostName

msktutil -N -c -b 'CN=COMPUTERS' -s $HostName/$HostName.$DomainName -k my-keytab.keytab --computer-name $HostName --upn $HostName$ --server $SystemName.$DomainName --user-creds-only

sudo mv my-keytab.keytab /etc/sssd/my-keytab.keytab

sudo mv /etc/sssd/sssd.conf /etc/sssd/sssd.conf.default

SSSDFILE="/etc/sssd/sssd.conf"
/bin/cat <<EOM >$SSSDFILE

[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = $DomainName

[nss]
entry_negative_timeout = 0
#debug_level = 5

[pam]
#debug_level = 5

[domain/$DomainName]
#debug_level = 10
enumerate = false
id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
chpass_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
dyndns_update = false
ad_hostname = $HostName.$DomainName
ad_server = $SystemName.$DomainName
ad_domain = $DomainName
ldap_schema = ad
ldap_id_mapping = true
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_sasl_mech = gssapi
ldap_sasl_authid = $HostName$
krb5_keytab = /etc/sssd/my-keytab.keytab
ldap_krb5_init_creds = true

EOM

sudo chmod 0600 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-session

sudo systemctl restart sssd
```

Comment: If I read your question correctly AD is not allowing the use of numbers but does work with names for login?

Comment: sorry for the delay in respond Yes it works with Name Eg syed

Answer (score 0):

This is because systemd has forbidden purely numeric usernames. You can work around it by appending the domain, e.g `01012578@DOMAIN`, but this reportedly causes other problems. I haven't yet found a proper solution to those new problems.